# Galois Field $\mathrm{GF}(4)$

Tags: galois-theory, associativity

I am trying to prove associativity for the following.

Addition:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+  & 0&   1&   B &  D  \\
\hline
    0&   0 &  1 &  B &  D \\ 
1 &  1 &  0 &  D &  B  \\
B &  B &  D &  0 &  1  \\
D &  D &  B &  1 &  0  \end{array}
$$

I tried a proof by contradiction and it is technically correct but it is too long and tedious and I am wondering if there is a better way that I haven't thought of. I don't really want the answer just like a push in the right direction.

Also, just wondering if I should try to define addition in like an algebraic way but again I don't understand how that would work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recognize that this is the same as the group $C_2\times C_2$, with $0\sim(0,0)$, $1\sim (1,0)$, $B\sim(0,1)$, and $D\sim(1,1)$.